# Data maturity monitors

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-analysis, data-warehouse

Does anyone know what data maturity monitors are and How to create data maturity monitors for a table in GCP?

I am new to gcp data engineering. I have tried in google but couldnt find what data maturity monitors are.

Comment: What  are you meaning as data maturity monitors? If is in the context of Data Quality, in Data Plex has a feature to it: https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/data-quality-overview

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements?